# XUnit tries to add dlls to a TestProject

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017, xunit

We have an Asp.net Core Project with a XUnit Test-Project. Since some Time, I think since updating to Asp.Net Core 2.1, we get the following Warning:
[image: SourceControl-Warning]

This Warning pops up every time we open the Solution in a new Branch and I have no clue how to get rid of it. Since both, the "Add" and the "Cancel" have no impact on the project.

Some more Data about the project:

- .net Core 2.1
- Xunit 2.4.0
- TFS 2017
- Visual Studio 15.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message seems the packages folder which contains the `*.dlls` or the  test project is not mapped to the workspace.

Generally you need to map your workspace at the **Project level**. Please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb668992(v=pandp.10)) on how to set up the source control folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't help me, because the article is from 2013 and our mapping worked fine for 1 year now, until a few months ago.

Comment: @Berger I just pointed out the cause of the problem. The knowledge of workspaces and project structure is applied to all versions of TFS. Suggest you check your workspaces to make sure that you have mapped the test project or dlls...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be harsh. 
The test project is mapped like all other projects, where /bin and /obj are by default not mapped. And the 3 dll Files only show up in the /bin folder of the Test project, after I build the solution. Even if I tell the source controll, to "Cancel add".